# Remove duplicate rows from pyspark dataframe which have same value but in different column

Tags: pyspark

I want to remove duplicate rows from two columns. Rows which contain two values has same records but are in reverse order.

```
|--------------|-------------------|
|   name       |   alt_name        |
|----------------------------------|
|  a10.samsung | a20.samsung       |
|  x.iphone    |  xr.iphone        |
|  3.nokia     |  5.nokia          |
| a20.samsung  | a10.samsung       |
| 5.nokia      | 3.nokia           |
|  xr.iphone   |  x.iphone         |
------------------------------------
```

I want following output;

```
|--------------|-------------------|
|   name       |   alt_name        |
|----------------------------------|
|  3.nokia     |  5.nokia          |
|  a10.samsung | a20.samsung       |
|  x.iphone    |  xr.iphone        |
------------------------------------
```

Comment: Its a different question in terms of removing duplicates from rows. The link which you refer has duplicates in same column with different rows. But in this case its in different column.

Comment: I have removed the flag. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it using spark sql:

I assume your original dataframe name as mobiles and code to remove duplicates:

```py
mobiles.createTempView('tablename')

newDF= spark.sql("select * from tablename where name<=alt_name")

newDF.show()
```